# T-SQL isnumeric() replacement in hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

What is the replacement for the T-SQL `isnumeric()` function in hive 0.10?

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent in HIVE but you can use the `cast` function.
Casting anything that isn't "numeric" to `double` will return null and you could use it like this :
`select x from table where cast(field as double) is not null`

Comment: I tried this, but it kept letting alphaumeric characters through. This was because "select cast('7E7' as double)"  resolves to "70000000", not null - so use "select x from table where cast(field as int) is not null"    instead

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a number is decimal or not by the below check. This can be given in where clause as well.

select case when abs(x%1)>0 then x else cast(x as bigint) end ;